# Fetch records where all associated records have attribute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Here are my classes:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end
```

Category has a `visible` booloean.

I need to create a scope in `Product` so that I can get all products which categories are all visibile (i.e.: if a Product has 10 categories, and even one category has `visible` set to false, the scope should discard the product).

Both ActiveRecord calls and MySQL queries are acceptable.

EDIT: we have hundreds of thousands of products and we'd need to delegate this operations to the database as we'll have to do pagination, sorting the the likes on this array of products.

Answer (score 1):

```
Product.where("id not in (select product_id from categories where visible='false')")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working: first, `categories` doesn't have a `category_id` column; second, if there is a Product with id 2, and a Category with visible set to false and id 2, even if the Product is not related to the Category, it would get excluded.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try finding out all Products that have :visible as false.Then minus this from all products.
`Product.all - Product.where('categories.visible=?', false).includes(:category)`

Comment: Thanks.
I wonder, wouldn't that array subtraction be delegated to Ruby? We have hundreds of thousands of products. Such calculation would probably be a disaster as we would need to do pagination on it, for example.